# write your pay computation with time-and-a-half for overtime and create a function called computepay which takes two parameters (hours and rate)

Tags: python-3.x, function

For the above question i have written this code . Math formula is correct but it is not giving the correct answer where is the fault?

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
    if hours<=40:
        pay = hours * rate
    else:
        pay = (((hours-40)*rate)*1.5)+rate*40
        return pay
x = input("Enter hours: ")
y = input("Enter rate: ")
a = float(x)
b = float(y)
pay = computepay(a, b)
print("Pay: ", pay)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `hours` is less than or equal to 40, `computepay()` doesn't return anything. Try changing the indent of the `return pay` line by four spaces, so it's indented by the same amount as the `else:`:

```py
def computepay(hours, rate):
    if hours<=40:
        pay = hours * rate
    else:
        pay = (((hours-40)*rate)*1.5)+rate*40
    return pay
```